# Dynamically change data adapters connection

Tags: c#, .net, dataadapter, sqldataadapter

I am using C#, .NET 4.5, VS2015.

I want to be able to change connection property of data adapter dynamically. (during run time).

Looking at connection property of data adapter, connection is a private setting:

```
private global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection _connection;

private void InitConnection() {
            this._connection = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
            this._connection.ConnectionString = global::Audit.Properties.Settings.Default.LoggingConnectionString;
        }
```

Is it possible to change connection of table adapter during run time?

**EDIT:**

Interesting thing is that for table adapters with select commands, connection property is public, so it's not a problem changing it. For adapters with insert commands, connection is private and I don't know how to change it. Of course, I am speaking about components dragged directly from server explorer to design view of the dataset.

Example for select command (generated as internal global):

```
 internal global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection Connection {
            get {
                if ((this._connection == null)) {
                    this.InitConnection();
                }
                return this._connection;
            }
```

Example for insert command (generated as private):

```
 private void InitCommandCollection() {
            this._commandCollection = new global::System.Data.IDbCommand[1];
            this._commandCollection[0] = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            ((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand)(this._commandCollection[0])).Connection = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(global::Audit.Properties.Settings.Default.LoggingConnectionString1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this limitation by creating my own ConnectionString property in the TableAdapter. You just need to make sure that it's part of the TableAdapter's namespace.

```
public partial class MyTableAdapter
{
    public string ConnectionString
    {
        set
        {
            if ((this._commandCollection == null))
            {
                this.InitCommandCollection();
            }

            for (int index = 0; index < this._commandCollection.Length; index++)
            {
                this._commandCollection[index].Connection.ConnectionString = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```